# Workstations across domain losing trust daily

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, login

We have a windows 2012 R2 domain with ~4 domain controllers spread out over 3 offices. Around two weeks ago, client computers running Windows 10 Pro began throwing the error "the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed" on login. This is fixed by a restart of the client, but always comes back within 24-48 hours.

We have examined the usual culprits of duplicate machine names, and time syncing, and neither appears to be an issue.

Any ideas on how to prevent this from constantly occurring?

Comment: Are the Windows 10 Pro computers cloned computers? If so make sure your master is not a domain member. Join it afterwards.

Comment: Good suggestion - they are not cloned computers, no clones anywhere on the network.

Comment: It's interesting that restarting makes the message go away. Try resetting the computer's AD password. 
Reset-ComputerMachinePassword [-Credential <PSCredential>] [-Server <String>]

Of course run this with a user account able to change computer account passwords and the -Server parameter will need to be a DC.

Comment: Using powershell is much more efficient than rejoining the computer to the domain. Run it from the problem computer.  If you are unable to, it can be run remotely via invoke-command.

Comment: The reboot workstation as a fix option is interesting... Possible issue with DC replication when workstations change their computer account password. Reboot may be temporarily putting workstation back in touch with healthy DC. Any user login issues? Have you verified the 4 DC's are replicating properly? Run: `repadmin /replsummary` also review event logs on DC's.

Comment: Does the 24-48 hours refer to the problem repeating on the same workstation, or a different workstation?

Comment: Applies to the same workstation - so now we have a domain with 4 dcs and ~300 computers, and all 300 workstations are getting this error every 24-48 hours, we've never restarted so often in our lives.

Comment: Table below doesn't format nicely, but I see one controller has error "The target principal name is incorrect." I'm guessing this is the source of our problems
Destination DSA     largest delta    fails/total %%   error
 DC1                      46m:29s    0 /  10    0
 DC3                      32m:19s    0 /  10    0
 DC4                      38m:54s    0 /  10    0
 DC5                      43m:23s    0 /  10    0
 DC6             >60 days           15 /  15  100  (2148074274) The target principal name is incorrect.

Comment: Success! I followed the directions here https://neilbryan.ca/the-target-principal-name-is-incorrect-active-directory-domain-controller-replication-issue/

Comment: Glad that helped and you found a fix. In the future, remember you can edit the original post to add more information like that. Within the message there are more formatting options than there are here in the comments. You can also post an answer with the steps you took fix and earn yourself some points.